# Printing all Strings from a list by passing in char variable

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to print all strings from a list by passing in a char variable.

And I pass in char p when I have something for example like

```
public static void printStrings(List<String> words, char p)
{

words.stream()
.filter(i -> i.startsWith(p)) 
.sorted()
.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

how would I pass in the char variable because I keep getting an error that says

```
error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
```

So how would I pass in a char variable without getting an error?

Comment: Not that if your want to print the strings sorted, `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach` is the correct choice, semantically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String::startsWith` can only accept `String` as argument.

Try

```
.filter(i -> i.startsWith(Character.toString(p)))
```

Comment: This requires creating a new string object each time the function to `filter` operation is called. which may as well be fine with the OP. Another more efficient version would be --> `.filter(i -> !i.isEmpty() && i.charAt(0) == p)`

Answer (score 3):

Converting the `char` to a `String` first. You can do that calling the method `String.valueOf(char)`

```
public static void printStrings(List<String> words, char p)
{

words.stream()
.filter(i -> i.startsWith(String.valueOf(p))) 
.sorted()
.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: This requires creating a new string object each time the function to `filter` operation is called. which may as well be fine with the OP. Another more efficient version would be --> `.filter(i -> !i.isEmpty() && i.charAt(0) == p)`